# Rotate Sheets in Google Spreadsheet every 10 sec

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have 5 sheets in my Google Spreadsheet document and i am trying to see if it is possible have a plugin or function to rotate each sheets every 10 sec?

Please let me know.
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Found this [thread](http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/508354-switch-betwen-excel-sheets-so-many-x-seconds.html) on how to set the spreadsheet to switch between the different sheets every N seconds.

Example:

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function GetAsyncKeyState Lib "user32" (ByVal vKey As Long) As Integer

Public Sub Switch()

  Dim ws As Worksheet

  Do
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
      ws.Activate
      Application.Wait Now() + TimeValue("00:00:05")
      If GetAsyncKeyState(vbKeyShift) Then Exit Sub
      DoEvents
    Next ws
  Loop

End Sub
```

This will loop through all worksheets in the current workbook every five seconds, then when it's done it loops round to do again.